# Definition of functions with def

Tags: scala, function

Trying in the repl:

```
scala> def add(x: Int) = 1 + x
add: (x: Int)Int

scala> add(2)
res0: Int = 3

scala> def add = (x: Int) => 1 + x
add: Int => Int

scala> add(2)
res1: Int = 3
```

I see "add" definitions differ in the type printed by the repl.
I guess the first definition is something like a method and the second is something like a function value.

What are the differences of defining add in one way or the other?
Is it one way preferable or discouraged?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between both definitions:

```
def add = (x: Int) => 1 + x
```

Each time you call `add` you are creating a new function `Int => Int`. You are basically defining a parameterless function `add` that returns a function `Int => Int`. This would be the complete signature:

```
def add: (Int => Int) = (x: Int) => 1 + x
```

A better way to write it:

```
val add = (x: Int) => 1 + x
```

Now you are defining a function `Int => Int` and assigning it to the value `add`, this will only occur once.

```
def add(x: Int) = 1 + x
val add = (x: Int) => 1 + x
```

These 2 definitions are equivalent.

Comment: In the first case you are defining a parameterless *method*, not a function! The two are completely different! It's a method which, every time you call it, returns a *new* function. In the second case, it's a field which every time you reference it, returns the *same* function.

Comment: "In many situations, you can ignore the difference between functions and methods and just think of them as the same thing" http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html So, first no I would not say they are *completely* different. Second, I did not want to confuse an obvious beginner with irrelevant details. Third, the second part of your comment is exactly what my answer explains.

Comment: Methods can be generic, functions can't. Methods can have implicit arguments, functions can't. Methods can have multiple argument lists, functions can't. Methods can have optional parameters with default arguments, functions can't. Methods can have repeated arguments, functions can't. Functions are objects, methods aren't (they belong to objects).

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you @JörgWMittag who have helped me understand this subject. Now I see there are functions (which are Objects) and methods (which belong to Objects). Quite confused at the beginning, but seeing the light now. A few more points: functions, being objects, have a type and methods associated; in some contexts where a function is expected, you can name a method and it gets wrapped into a function which calls the method, in other cases you have to do it explicitly with "_" after the method name.